# Time difference giving positive value when it should be negative

Tags: javascript

To calculate the difference between now and a time X, I'm using the following:

```
var splitPickDate= startDate.split('/');
var splitPick = startTime.split(':');
var timeCalc = new Date(parseInt(splitPickDate[2]),parseInt(splitPickDate[0]),parseInt(splitPickDate[1]), parseInt(splitPick[0]), parseInt(splitPick[1]));
var now = new Date();
var diffNow = timeCalc - now;
```

Assuming `splitPickDate = '01/28/2015'`, `splitPick = '00:00'` and `now = Wed Jan 28 2015 15:35:04 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)` should I not get a negative value for `diffNow`?

Am I wrong in calculating the time difference between the two times?

Comment: Timezones, probably. What is the timezone for `timeCalc`?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol The timezone for both is India Standard Time

Comment: @atmd I'm using this calculation to check if the `timeCalc` occurs before or after `now`. So I can't use that calculation. Shouldn't `new Date()` work the same way for both the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think thats because in JS when you use numbers for months January = 0, February = 1, etc.

Your code just uses 1 from the string which creates a date for 28 February, instead of 28 January. So you subtract a January time from a February time. Which is sure positive.

With this. your calculation will be ok for those particular dates:

```
var timeCalc = new Date(parseInt(splitPickDate[2]),parseInt(splitPickDate[0]),parseInt(splitPickDate[1]), parseInt(splitPick[0]), parseInt(splitPick[1]));
```

Comment: Aah, you're absolutely right. I didn't realise. Thank you! :)

Comment: Actually I forgot it too. I had to check it with some quick test in the browser console. :)
But I glad to be able to help.